# How to capture checkbox input

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, ajax, rest

I am learning web development and I have run into one problem. I have four checkbox in my form and I need to capture the state of checked checkboxes. Also I need to send the checked checkboxes id to the REST Service where I need to perform DIFFERENT operation for each of the checked checkboxes.

Below is what I have done till now.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<form>
<input type="checkbox" class = "checkBoxProp" id = "1" name="checkBoxProp" value="1">Graph1<br> 
<input type="checkbox" class = "checkBoxProp" id = "2" name="checkBoxProp" value="2">Graph2<br> 
<input type="checkbox" class = "checkBoxProp" id = "3" name="checkBoxProp" value="3">Graph3<br> 
<input type="checkbox" class = "checkBoxProp" id = "4" name="checkBoxProp" value="4">Graph4<br> 
<input id="btnGetResponse" type="button" value="ClickMe!"/> 
</form>
<div> </div>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$("#btnGetResponse").click(function()
{
var ids = []; // empty array
$('.checkBoxProp:checked').each(function() {
    ids.push($(this).val()); // returning the value of the current element of all the elements selected
});
console.log(JSON.stringify(ids.join()));
 $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "http://localhost:51349/SMS_Rest.svc/v1/usercheckboxes",
    data:  JSON.stringify(ids.join()) ,
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    dataType: "json",
    success: function(response)
    {
       sessionStorage.setItem(1, response);
         window.location.href = "../backbonetest/dashboardUI.html";
    },
    failure: function(response) 
    {
        alert('fail');
    }
    });
})
```

What I have done above is firstly selected all the checked checkboxes and pushed them into an array and then used `join()` to convert it into complete string and then converted it into JSON and sent.

For example if first and third checkboxes are checked the value sent is in format
of `"1,3"` to my Rest Service. Now since data of checkbox is being sent as string format altogether, at REST Service I will have to parse/split this string `(,)` and then perform necessary action. At REST all I want something like

```
if (firstcheckbox selected) // do something
if(secondcheckbox selected)// do something
```

Question: haven't I overcomplicated things. Do I really need to put all the checkboxes in an array and even if Yes then do I need to use `join()` and then stringify to send it to the rest service. Can I find a way where I do not need to Parse/Split the sent string at my REST Service to get all the checked checkbox id. I am new to all this. Please guide me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Use `jQueryObject.map` to get `checked` checkbox values
- As you are defining `contentType` as `"application/json; charset=utf-8"`, no need to `stringify` the content.
- Have a `key` for `data` object so that server can access the data using specified `key`

```js
$("#btnGetResponse").click(function() {
  var ids = $('.checkBoxProp:checked').map(function() {
    return this.value;
  }).get();
  console.log(JSON.stringify(ids.join()));
  $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "http://localhost:51349/SMS_Rest.svc/v1/usercheckboxes",
    data: {
      ids: ids
    },
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    dataType: "json",
    success: function(response) {
      sessionStorage.setItem(1, response);
      window.location.href = "../backbonetest/dashboardUI.html";
    },
    failure: function(response) {
      alert('fail');
    }
  });
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form>
  <input type="checkbox" class="checkBoxProp" id="1" name="checkBoxProp" value="1">Graph1
  <br>
  <input type="checkbox" class="checkBoxProp" id="2" name="checkBoxProp" value="2">Graph2
  <br>
  <input type="checkbox" class="checkBoxProp" id="3" name="checkBoxProp" value="3">Graph3
  <br>
  <input type="checkbox" class="checkBoxProp" id="4" name="checkBoxProp" value="4">Graph4
  <br>
  <input id="btnGetResponse" type="button" value="ClickMe!" />
</form>
```

Comment: If I select two checkboxes log gives me output as `"2,4"`. So what is the key here for "2" and "4" values. Please bear with me I am a beginner

Comment: @Unbreakable — In data object `{
      ids: ids
    }`, ids is the key..

Comment: One last doubt. How to capture this in REST. What should be the map datatype. is it map<int,int>?

Comment: @Unbreakable, Not sure what you are asking but `ids` will be the key to access data over server side...

Comment: Generally map works with key value pair, and each key uniquely identifies a value. But currently at Sever the value I am receiving is `ids%5B%5D=2&ids%5B%5D=3` (I have selected 2nd and 3rd checkboxes). So both value 2 and 3 has same Key as "ids".

Comment: Unless the keys are different how can I distinguish different checkboxes.

Comment: @Unbreakable, Can you provide a fiddle ? Snippet provided above working fine.

Comment: Your snippet works just fine. Only thing is I don't know how to capture it at server. Like I have a function where I need to capture this. But what should that function accept as an argument. `void function (accept Incoming Data)` . Now what should be the data type so that I can capture the stuff coming from front end.

Comment: @Unbreakable — Remove `contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",` and check...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/115758/discussion-between-unbreakable-and-rayon).

Comment: Thanks a lot Rayon. Finally I am able to get the value of selected checkbox at server. The issue was at the server side.